# Install ROS2 Dependent Packages

Tags: gazebo, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I am trying to install ROS 2 Dependent Packages on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

When I write " curl -sSL http://get.gazebosim.org | sh", "sh: 2: Syntax error: newline unexpected" appear.

Do you know how to solve this error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/342985/install-ros2-dependent-packages/) by [shunta ito](https://answers.ros.org/users/51343/shunta-ito/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-01-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-31**:\

> I am trying to install ROS 2 Dependent Packages on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

please always link to whichever instructions or tutorial(s) you are trying to follow.

We don't know everything by heart, which makes it difficult to figure out what you're attempting/supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like there's something wrong with the server hosting that page:

[image: something went wrong]

I'd suggest contacting the Gazebo folks over at `answers.gazebosim.org`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-31**:
If/when you post at `answers.gazebosim.org`, please post a comment here with a link to your new question, so we can keep things connected.